# Embedding Instagram via shortcode doesn't work as advertised in official docs

Tags: shortcode, embed

I am coding up a simple Wordpress theme and I would like to embed Instagram images via shortcode as described on [Wordpress.com](https://en.support.wordpress.com/instagram/instagram-images/) and [Instagram.com](https://instagram.com/developer/embedding/). (Both links point to the very pages that demonstrate how this should be working).

So either `http://instagram.com/p/bNd86MSFv6/`or 
`[instagram url=http://instagram.com/p/bNd86MSFv6/ hidecaption=true width=320]` should be OK to embed an image from Instagram.

However, they don't embed anything. Youtube and Vimeo work fine, but not Instagram. The URL just gets wrapped in a `<p>` tag.  The page about oEmbed on Wordpress says, this should be [supported since 3.5](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds), I currently have WP 4.0 installed on my localhost.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here is WordPress **COM** and **ORG** are **NOT** equal. Questions about support for the former are actually *off-topic* on WordPress Development.

One consequence of the non-equality of com and org is that the latter has no shortcode `[instagram]`, so naturally it won't work - the built-in shortcodes can be seen at this [list](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode#Built-In_and_Additional_Shortcodes). On the other hand, you are right, according to the [codex page about embeds](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds) Instagram is supported. Normally it works like this:

```
Instagram photo below

http://instagram.com/p/bNd86MSFv6/

Instagram photo above
```

It is important that the embeds link is on a separate line.

If that is not working for you, then you can try using the [`[embed]` shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embed_Shortcode):

```
[embed]http://instagram.com/p/bNd86MSFv6/[/embed]
```

BTW tested the Instagram embed on a old WP 4.0 installation, it works just fine for me.

Comment: Thank you, I knew com and org are different, but I have secretly hoped that shortcodes would work on both 'editions', because the oEmbed page lists Instagram since v. 3.5.

Comment: Sure, the hope dies last, I guess. That said, you can always create your own custom shortcode, in case you need some extra functionality, in addition to the standard embed feature. @DrunkenMaster